# Failed completely to run the react native app on real device

Tags: react-native

I have tried most of solutions on the stackoverflow and github issues related to react native but all in vain... for almost 2 weeks.

**Environment**
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
Window 10 Pro
Using android device 5.1(lollilop)

well the app ran successful in expo client but i need to run the native code.
**First error: Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows**
so i was able to run   command below  and the error disappeared on the phone client

`react-native run-android && adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
But this error has persisted on the package server console

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'BALR_X7 - 5.1' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Running C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppDat                                                                                                                a\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb -s 7DM7R4KJ99999999 revers                                                                                                                e tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Local\Android\S                                                                                                                dk;C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/a                                                                                                                db ENOENT
Starting the app on 7DM7R4KJ99999999 (C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Local\Android\                                                                                                                Sdk;C:\Users\goldsoft25\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/                                                                                                                adb -s 7DM7R4KJ99999999 shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.                                                                                                                MainActivity)...
```

**2nd error**
development server return error response code --> 500  on the android device
Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ensure that i downloaded all the needed API android sdk build tools  in my case API 28.0.3 and API 28...
then i  run the command below.. pay attention to the location of the android sdk tools

```
goldsoft25@GOLDSOFTX MINGW64 ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
$ adb devices
```

then later i run the command below in the same command line as below

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then later i was able to run `react-native run-android` and it worked perfectly